# jquery assign new value to vars on window resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I'm pretty new to jQuery and hope to find some help from you guys.
I managed to create some scrolling function that works with dynamic built content.

I have a couple of DIVs to which I want to "scrollTo". These Divs are
always as big as the viewport. Everything works fine until I resize the window. on window resize the 
resizeDiv and the setScrollingPoints are fired again. The now is that the animation goes to the old coordinates and slowly scrolls then to the right position.

I found out, that the resize functions is called multiple times and therefore the setScrollingPoints function is fire multiple times as well. What I don't understand is why the old positions are not overwritten. Maybe you can help me out...

Thx a lot!
Dan

My code looks like that:

```
 function resizeDiv(target) {

      // resizing Divs
      var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
      var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

      $(target).height(viewportHeight).width(viewportWidth);

 } // end resize Divs


 function setScrollingPoints() {
      var wallpapers = $('.wallpaper');
      var buttons = $('.button');

      var scrollPositions = new Array();

      // Cache Wallpaper positions
      wallpapers.each(function(i) {
           scrollPositions[i] = Math.round($(this).offset().top);
       $(this).addClass('wallpaper'+ i);
      });


      // setting next Buttons
      buttons.each(function(i) {
           $(this).attr('id','button'+i);
      if(i == wallpapers.length - 1) {
           $(this).remove();
      }

 });

  $('.nextButton').click(function() {

    // get button id
    var elementID = $(this).attr('id');

    // remove alpha characters from id and convert it to a numeric var
    elementID = parseInt(elementID.replace(/\D/g,''));

    var next = elementID + 1;
    var previous = elementID -1;

    var nextWallpaper = '.wallpaper' + next;
    var previousWallpaper = '.wallpaper' + previous;


    if(!(next == wallpapers.length)) {
        $('html, body').scrollTo(scrollPositions[elementID+1]);
    });


  });

  $(window).resize(function() {

          resizeDiv('.wallpaper');
          setScrollingPoints();

  });



$(document).ready(function() {

// resize all wallpaper elements to viewport size
resizeDiv('.wallpaper');

// set scrollingPositions
setScrollingPoints();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In setScrollingPoints, change:

```
var scrollPositions = new Array();
```

to

```
scrollPositions = new Array();
```

If you take the var keyword from infront of your referenced to scrollPositions, you will be talking about the global scope scrollPositions, which would be accessible to any of your functions.

**Different Issue:**

You have

```
$(this).addClass('wallpaper'+ i);
```

in setScrollingPoints. You're not removing previous classes.

**Final Issue**

Just looked at your JSfiddle (thank you for making it for me).

Your problem isn't your array. Inside of `setScrollingPoints()` you're setting the click listener:

```
$('.nextButton').click(function() {
```

This *doesn't* overwrite the previous listener, it just adds another one. You need to add this:

```
$('.nextButton').off("click");
```

above `$('.nextButton').click(function() {`

you were simply triggering all of the old listeners on each button.

Comment: uuuups, sorry I had an old version of document.ready in there. I tried to alert scrollPositions and after the resize this array gets multidimensional. how can i clear the array before reassign new values?

Comment: thanks Glitcher, but I still have the same issue. To be precise, the array is still getting multidimensional but now all instances have the right final position. but like that the scrollto is still fired multiple times and further scrolling is not possible until all the scrollto's are finished.

Comment: I changed `$('html, body').scrollTo(scrollPositions[elementID+1]);` to `$('html, body').stop().scrollTo(scrollPositions[elementID+1]);` now it works but it is only a workaround since the array is getting bigger and bigger every time the window is resized.

Comment: Different issue: I've seen that but it seems that the old classes with the same name are overwritten. I can't see any doubled classes in firebug after resizing.

Comment: try using console.log($(".wallpaper").length); and tell me whether or not that number increases each time you resize the window (this will print out the value in the javascript console)

Comment: checked that already. it does not increase. when I alert(scrollPositions), I get at page load 1 alert with 3 numbers (0,1200,2400) since I have currently 3 wallpapers displayed. When I resize the window I get multiple alerts with 3 numbers. The amount of alerts depends on how lang my resizing movement is.

Comment: if you're getting 3 numbers in each alert then there is only 3 numbers in the array. Can you put your code into a jsfiddle so I can look at it properly please?

Comment: Wow, u saved me thx! I'll read up on that off-function! Thx mate!